# Execute a Bash script (Shell Script) from postgres function/procedure/trigger

Tags: bash, postgresql, perl, centos, postgresql-11

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION test() RETURNS boolean AS $$
$filename = '/home/postgres';
if (-e $filename) { 
exec /home/postgres/test.sh &
return true; }
return false;
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

exec /home/postgres/test.sh &  its showing syntax error.
Could you please help how to call bash script into postgres funtion/procedure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, the code needs to be syntactically valid Perl. So you'll need to clean up a few bits.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION test() RETURNS boolean AS $$
  my $filename = '/home/postgres';
  if (-e $filename) { 
    system '/home/postgres/test.sh' and return 1;
  }
  return;
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

I've changed a few things:

- I declare the variable `$filename` using `my`
- I used `system` instead of `exec`. `exec` replaces the current process - effectively never returning to the calling function
- `system` expects to be passed a string. So I've added quotes around the command
- `and` is usually better in flow control statements than `&&` (and always much better than `&` which is for bit-flipping, not flow control)
- Perl doesn't have `true` and `false`, so I've replaced `true` with 1 (which is a true value in Perl). And I've removed the `false` from the other `return` statement - the default behaviour of `return` is to return a false value

I don't have a Postgresql installation to test this on. If it still doesn't work, please tell us what errors you get.

Comment: I'm not a Perl guru, but there seems to be a missing single quote in the `system` line.

Comment: its working fine for me. Thank you so much Dave for your help.

Comment: It's bad practice to use `return` when the sub is expected to return a scalar (because the sub won't always return a scalar). `return 0` would make more sense here.

Comment: It's worth noting that Perl has two *logical and* operators that differ in precedence.  The high precedence form `&&` is great for compactly writing logical expressions, like `$foo == 27 && $bar >= 5`.  The low precedence form is best used for flow control, like `assert_we_are_done() and return 1;` (`or` gets used for this much more frequently).

Answer (score 1):

pl/sh exists, and can be used as a procedual language.

https://github.com/petere/plsh